# CSS 'd' <path> attribute doesn't work in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, svg

I have a generated code that I CAN't modify directly because it is generated by a huge JS code, a part of it generates a svg shape, I could override it in CSS. but my code doesn'T work in FF !!!

here is the origical code :

```
<div id="map_outer" style="position: absolute; left: 3px; z-index: 1;">
<svg height="35" version="1.1" width="35" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative;"><desc style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">Created with Raphaël 2.1.0</desc>
<defs style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">
</defs>
<path fill="#cecece" stroke="#808080" d="M503.7,743.8C694,647.1999999999999,636.6,326.74999999999994,348.1,334.09V205.39L120.00000000000003,400.39L348.1,606.19V474.59000000000003C589,469.09000000000003,578,677.3900000000001,503.70000000000005,743.8900000000001Z" stroke-width="40" stroke-opacity="1" fill-opacity="1" transform="matrix(0.05,0,0,0.05,-1.9,-5.7)" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); stroke-opacity: 1; fill-opacity: 1; cursor: pointer;">
</path>
</svg>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS code that override the generated 'd' property :

```
#map_outer svg path{
    fill: rgb(255, 204, 0) !important;
    d:path("M 850 300 C 850 300 350 300 350 300 L 348.1 205.39 L 120 400.39 L 348.1 606.19 L 350 500 C 850 500 850 500 850 500 z") !important;
    stroke-width: 0;
}
```

the code doesn't work in Firefox. But works in Chrome.

[image]

Comment: Would mind to use jQuery or JavaScript to achieve this behaviour?

Comment: No problem, any solution

Comment: checkout answer below

Comment: Firefox does not yet support setting the d attribute of a path in CSS. If and when it does so it will not support the path() syntax as that is obsolete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var pathD = "M 850 300 C 850 300 350 300 350 300 L 348.1 205.39 L 120 400.39 L 348.1 606.19 L 350 500 C 850 500 850 500 850 500 z";

$("#map_outer svg path").attr("d", pathD);
```

```css
#map_outer svg path{
    fill: rgb(255, 204, 0) !important;
    d:path("M 850 300 C 850 300 350 300 350 300 L 348.1 205.39 L 120 400.39 L 348.1 606.19 L 350 500 C 850 500 850 500 850 500 z") !important;
    stroke-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="map_outer" style="position: absolute; left: 3px; z-index: 1;">
<svg height="35" version="1.1" width="35" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative;"><desc style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);-moz-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">Created with Raphaël 2.1.0</desc>
<defs style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);-moz-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">
</defs>
<path fill="#cecece" stroke="#808080" d="M503.7,743.8C694,647.1999999999999,636.6,326.74999999999994,348.1,334.09V205.39L120.00000000000003,400.39L348.1,606.19V474.59000000000003C589,469.09000000000003,578,677.3900000000001,503.70000000000005,743.8900000000001Z" stroke-width="40" stroke-opacity="1" fill-opacity="1" transform="matrix(0.05,0,0,0.05,-1.9,-5.7)" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); stroke-opacity: 1; fill-opacity: 1; cursor: pointer;">
</path>
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Somehow is doesn't work for me in my code : I use it in Typo3 and I must write jQuery instead of $ ,  <script>
    var pathD = "M 850 300....";
    jQuery("#map_outer svg path").attr("d", pathD);
</script>

Comment: This won't fix the fact that the CSS is not understood by Firefox.

Comment: @Pointy I totally agree with you, that's why I asked bourax if he is open for alternative solution and then I've posted this solution and It works.